# java inheritance accessing super class variables inside subclass?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have below class.

```
public class A {
    private String name;
    private String age;
    //getters and setters
}

public class B extends A {
    // Some setters and getters
}

public class C extends B {
    // here can i access name and age properties using public getters of A ?
}
```

Can I access A class members in Class C ?

Thanks!

Comment: yes! you can get the values

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP can easily confirm this.

Comment: It's not a duplicate of that. Suggesting it is almost as bad as the OP - you've done a search and not even followed the link!

Answer (score 1):

The answer, as per the example, is no. The class members are marked as `private` thus are private to A.

Either use getters and setters, or change the visibility using `protected` or `public`.

You are getting voted down because you have not tried the code before posting it, and it is not a constructive question (it's a yes/no question which is not what the SO format is designed for).